# Make chrome to download mp3

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, mp3

As you know, chrome is playing an mp3 file using it's own player. But I need to download it to my file system.. I tryed this, but do not have any result:

```
$('.audio_download').click(function(){
    var s = $(this).attr('value');
    $('body').append('<iframe src='+s+' class="dlframe"></iframe>');
    $('iframe.dlframe').ready(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I checked console and I found there this: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mpeg: "*some-url*.mp3".

Comment: You might need to send specific headers to the browser from the server end.

Answer (score 2):

Set attribute "download" like

```
<a href='file.mp3' download='Very-Very-Good.mp3'>download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify htaccess like so http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/force-files-to-download-not-open-in-browser/ on your web server

Comment: It's not my web-server. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have any access to serverside code? As Ivan said in the comment to your question, you can set a content-disposition: attachment; to cause the file download instead of opening in the browser. I'm unaware of any way to do this purely with html/javascript